# How to replace a specific value in a Column on Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to replace a specific value in my whole Column D.

My Column looks like this:

```
COLUMN D
TD10.LU89.AX300.MT01
TD10.LU89.BT100.MT01
TD10.LU89.BP130.MP01
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to replace only the first "." with ".IO."

This is what I have already tried:

```
Columns("D").Replace _
What:=".", Replacement:=".IO.", LookAt:=xlPart
```

and obiviously the result is that all the points will be changed:

```
TD10.IO.LU89.IO.AX300.IO.MT01
```

Do you guy have a solution to my problem? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If your data always starts with `TD10.` then you can try replace `TD10.` with `TD10.IO.` in your vba code.

Comment: Unfortunately it changes always but the point stays always at the 5th position. I also tried with `????.` but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

    'Change sheet if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find the last row of column D
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop column D
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Replace the first occurance
            str = Replace(.Range("D" & i).Value, ".", ".IO.", , 1)
            .Range("D" & i).Value = str
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Really Like this code, much easier to understand but nothing happens when I try it. What I'm missing?

Comment: In line `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` replace `Sheet1` with the sheet name of your sheet. Have in mind that the results will be print in the immediate window

Comment: I have already changed the Sheet name. Probably what I'm missing is where the results are. I presume `Debug.Print` print the results in another windows!? Why not directly on my Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
Sub ReplaceDot()
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In Range("D1:D" & Rows.End(xlUp).Row)
        cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, 4) & ".IO." & Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 5)
    Next cl
End Sub
```

In case left part is of varying length:

`cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, InStr(cl.Value, ".") - 1) & ".IO." & Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - InStr(cl.Value, "."))`

One can make it more universal by adding `column` and `replacement` string as params to the sub