# My second sub doesn't work when called in the first sub but works if started separately

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to call my second sub from my first one.

The first one browses for a file:

```
Sub browseFilePath()
    On Error GoTo err
    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim filePath

    'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

    With fileExplorer
        If .Show = -1 Then 'Any file is selected
            filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            Workbooks.Open filePath

            Call Makro1 ' *** That's the second macro I want to call ***

        Else ' else dialog is cancelled
            MsgBox "Process Annulled"
            filePath = "" ' when cancelled set blank as file path.
        End If
    End With
err:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I select the chosen file, I open it and then I run the second macro.

It doesn't work completely. But If I run it separately it works.

Here is the makro1:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim str As String

'Change sheet if needed
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LEMT_Datenpunkte_SAIA")
    'Find the last row of column D
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ' REMOVE T*
    'Loop column D
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        'Replace the first occurance
        str = Replace(.Range("D" & i).Value, "*.", "", 6, 1)
            .Range("D" & i).Value = str
    Next i

    ' ADD .IO.
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        'Replace the first occurance
        str = Replace(.Range("D" & i).Value, ".", ".IO.", , 1)
            .Range("D" & i).Value = str
    Next i

    ' ADD RESERVE AGAIN
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        'Replace the first occurance
        str = Replace(.Range("D" & i).Value, "ve", "Reserve", , 1)
            .Range("D" & i).Value = str
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `Makro1` do? Does it have any implicit `ActiveWorkbook` or `ActiveSheet` - have you fully qualified all range/sheet references? What does "it doesn't work completely" mean? Presumably `Makro1` should be passed a workbook reference, but more detail is needed to confirm.

Comment: You can find here what the first makro1 does: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900131/how-to-replace-a-specific-value-in-a-column-on-excel-vba/57902556?noredirect=1#comment102226473_57902556) I'm pretty new in VBA world, I'm trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: I would suggest you take out the `On Error Goto err` line.  This is saying to exit the sub anytime you find an error.  Not a good debugging practice.

Comment: Can you still share the exact code by [edit]ing your question? And explain what is not working.

Comment: you got to replace `ThisWorkbook` By the workbooks name

Comment: Ok Darrell, I will do how you said. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: No.. pass a workbook reference to `Makro1`.

Comment: I made `Makro1` just a message box and it worked.  You may have an error in `Makro1` that is being ignored.

Comment: I added the makro1, so you can see it.

Comment: Is `Makro1` located in the newly opened file or is it located in the file that contains the first macro?  Also, where does it err now and what is the error.

Comment: Makro 1 is located in the file that contains the first macro (Better to say is located in the same macro). I tried it now again and it just doesn't work but give no errors. When I run it separately it works.

Comment: I am confused why you would open another file and run a macro in the existing file.  If `Worksheets("LEMT_Datenpunkte_SAIA"` is in the new file, then it is not in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: With the first file I just want to create a button that open a second file (in my case always the `Worksheets("LEMT_Datenpunkte_SAIA")` and in this file want to run the `Makro1` Where is my error now?

Answer (score 0):

In first macro...

```
Call Makro1(filepath)
```

Then..

```
Sub Macro1(MyNewWorkbook as Workbook)

    With MyNewWorkbook.Worksheets("LEMT_Datenpunkte_SAIA")
```

Pretty much what @BigBen said

Comment: Doing like that it gives me an error saying: Type of argument ByRef incompatible. It marks the code `Call Makro1 (filePath)`

Comment: Sorry, take out the parentheses

Comment: You will want to extract just the workbook name from the filepath and pass that on.  Here is some reading on the many ways you can call a macro from another workbook https://exceloffthegrid.com/how-to-run-a-macro-from-another-workbook/

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks for your help.

Comment: within this answer, don't use `Call Makro1(filepath)`, just use `Makro1 filepath`. Gets rid of the whole `Call ` ambiguity and is better VBA coding. (`Call` was officially deprecated at one point in time, although the official docs no longer say this)

Comment: I resolved it just changing `With MyNewWorkbook.Worksheets("LEMT_Datenpunkte_SAIA")` to `With Excel.Worksheets("LEMT_Datenpunkte_SAIA")`